# Уважаемые эксперты, помогите, пожалуйста. Не могу понять, где именно нужно ставить запятую

Tags: пунктуация

Если вы(,)так же как и я, трудитесь над своими целями, пока другие отдыхают, огромный вам респект.

Подскажите, запятую нужно ставить именно так, как указано выше или же вот так: «Если вы так же, как и я, трудитесь над своими целями,...»

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вы, ***так же как и я***, трудитесь над своими **целевыми проектами**, пока другие отдыхают, огромное вам уважение.

Это нейтральный (книжный) стиль. Если вы используете слово ***респект,*** то должны иметь в виду, что это сленговое слово, хотя на форумах оно и применяется, например: *Хочу выразить свой респект ведущему, был на тренинге по риторике, не новичок в этой теме, но открыл много нового.*

**Пояснение**

1) В данном случае сравнительный союз ***так же как и*** не расчленяется запятой (он синонимичен союзу ***как и***).

http://www.gramota.tv/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_738

2) Но этот вариант нужно отличать от тех предложений, в которых  местоимение ***так*** и частица ***же*** не входят в союз, а относятся, например, к сказуемому:

Если вы не отдыхаете в праздники и **относитесь к работе так же**, как и я, большое вам уважение.

В таком предложении нерасчлененный союз ***так же как и*** нельзя использовать.

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

Я полагаю, что в заданном предложении ответ **однозначный (союз не расчленяется), то есть нет вариантов.** Дело в том, что оборот находится **в середине предложения**, а в этом случае союз не расчленяется.  http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=147#pp147

Розенталь сравнивает такой оборот **с придаточным предложением,** находящимся в середине главного, там тоже расчленение  составного союза в такой позиции невозможно.

Таким образом, возможен вариант: Если вы трудитесь **так же, как я...** Но однозначно: Если вы, **так же как и я,** трудитесь...

Comment: "Целевые проекты" сильно лучше, чем "цели"? В смысле трудиться над ними?.. Стало заковыристей, длиннее, канцеляритнее. Но вряд ли лучше.

Comment: Вам бы ЛУЧШЕ свой ответ проверить и убрать лишнюю запятую, в таком виде его следует считать неверным.

Comment: Зачем? Написанное пером, как говорится, не поймаешь... Да и Людмила этот вариант вполне допускает.

А вот "большое вам уважение" - это даже хуже "респекта". Что-то не так у вас с языковым чутьем.

Comment: Людмила рассматривает два варианта, а у Вас третий, неверный.

Comment: А-а, верно. Но все равно менять не буду.

Answer (score 0):

Если вы, так же, как и я, трудитесь над своими целями, пока другие отдыхают, огромный вам респект.

Но у меня маленький вопрос... Что такое "трудиться над целями"?! И маленькое замечание. Если уж написали "респект", то надо непременно добавить "и уважуха".

Answer (score 0):

Зависит от смысла, который Вы вкладываете в предложение.

Словарь-справочник по пунктуации объясняет: ( Справочно-информационный интернет-портал ГРАМОТА.РУ. В. В. Свинцов, В. М. Пахомов, И. В. Филатова. 2010.)

> Так же(,) как (и) союз; наречие + частица + союз
>
> 1. Союз. То же, что «равно как (и)». Синтаксические конструкции с союзом «так же как (и)» выделяются знаками препинания (запятыми).
>      Между частями союза знаки препинания не требуются. Так же как в
>      средневековой харчевне, нас встречали дома бревенчатые темные стены,
>      законопаченные желтым мхом, пылающие поленья в печке и запах тмина. К.
>      Паустовский, Бакенщик. Я знала, так же как и она, что рано или поздно
>      наступит день, когда мы поневоле заговорим и простим друг другу долгое
>      молчание. Ч. Айтматов, Материнское поле.
> 2. Наречие + частица + союз. Запятая ставится перед словом «как». От тяжелой росистой травы кругом и от цветов, ночных цветов, только
>      теперь раскрывших свои головки, пахло так же, как от волос Анны. С.
>      Сергеев-Ценский, Печаль полей. Совершенно так же, как в жмурках,
>      бывало мы, ребята, шли с завязанными глазами, так и она переступала с
>      лапки на лапку в направлении леса. М. Пришвин, Охотничьи собаки.

Если это первый случай и **так же как (и)** - составной союз, то запятая перед ним, не внутри, и смысл:

*Если вы, **так же как и я,** трудитесь над своими целями, пока другие отдыхают, огромный вам респект.* (Если вы трудитесь, как и я)

Если второй и  **так же** - наречие с частицей, то запятая после него, перед сравнительным оборотом:

*Если вы **так же**, как и я, трудитесь над своими целями, пока другие отдыхают, огромный вам респект.* (Если вы трудитесь как? **так же**, как и я)

По-моему, это первый случай.